# Application Stops after i click an item on the app drawer

Tags: android, drawer

I am having a problem with  the framework which I have downloaded from the Github . 
I have imported it in Android studio and I have made a few changes which consists on adding a new activity which can be launched from the app drawer . 
I tried lunching the new activity like this

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), WorkOrderActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

It compiles but when I click it, that app stops the logcat shows :

```
11-15 09:39:52.681 3852-3874/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: ModernAsyncTask #1
                                             Process: com.odoo, PID: 3852
                                             java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
                                                 at android.support.v4.content.ModernAsyncTask$3.done(ModernAsyncTask.java:161)
                                                 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
                                                 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
                                                 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
                                                 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
                                                 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
                                                 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
                                              Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot bind argument at index 1 because the index is out of range.  The statement has 0 parameters.
                                                 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.bind(SQLiteProgram.java:212)
                                                 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.bindString(SQLiteProgram.java:166)
                                                 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.bindAllArgsAsStrings(SQLiteProgram.java:200)
                                                 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:47)
                                                 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1314)
                                                 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQueryBuilder.query(SQLiteQueryBuilder.java:400)
                                                 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQueryBuilder.query(SQLiteQueryBuilder.java:294)
                                                 at com.odoo.core.orm.provider.BaseModelProvider.query(BaseModelProvider.java:107)
                                                 at android.content.ContentProvider.query(ContentProvider.java:857)
                                                 at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.query(ContentProvider.java:200)
                                                 at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:461)
                                                 at android.support.v4.content.ContentResolverCompatJellybean.query(ContentResolverCompatJellybean.java:33)
                                                 at android.support.v4.content.ContentResolverCompat$ContentResolverCompatImplJB.query(ContentResolverCompat.java:57)
                                                 at android.support.v4.content.ContentResolverCompat.query(ContentResolverCompat.java:125)
                                                 at android.support.v4.content.CursorLoader.loadInBackground(CursorLoader.java:59)
                                                 at android.support.v4.content.CursorLoader.loadInBackground(CursorLoader.java:37)
                                                 at android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader.onLoadInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:299)
                                                 at android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.doInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:57)
                                                 at android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.doInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:45)
                                                 at android.support.v4.content.ModernAsyncTask$2.call(ModernAsyncTask.java:138)
                                                 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 
                                                 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) 
                                                 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Does anyone have any idea what may be wrong .
Looking forward to your responses .

Best Regards

Comment: The WorkOrderActivity is Actually fine, but it's seems the activity trying to do something and that's when something goes wrong.. please attach the activity code for further investigation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Navigation Drawer then you should override this method

```
@Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.your_view_id) {
            //start your activity here
           }
}
```

and if you set the click listener in your View then you should use

```
@Override
 public void onClick(View v) {
  switch (view.getId()){
   case R.id.your_view_id:
    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), WorkOrderActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    break;
 }
}
```